# How can I provide secure web content to mobile devices that can't access an intranet?

Tags: security, mobile-devices

I'm working with a client on development web content for their intranet.  We want users to be able to access a version of the content on their mobile devices, but most of them don't have the VPN capability to get on to their intranet.

I'm wondering if anyone has had experience with this and can recommend a solution.

One other thing to consider is that the content is not mission critically secure.  If someone outside the company gained access to it, it would not represent a major issue, only a minor annoyance.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [client-side SSL certs](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500) yet?

Comment: Many phones don't support that either.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider creating an employee portal using server-side SSL and password authentication.  Insurance companies widely do this for their brokers for policy entry, for example.

The benefits of creating a new portal are that it could be designed for mobiles and also be denied access to (and sanitized of) confidential information.

Answer (score 1):

Allow public access to the intranet from out side by using port forwarding on your gateway/firewall.

You can additionally assign a domain name (usually a specific sub domain) to your external IP address and within your LAN you can overwrite the DNS for this specific DNS record so that the name inside and outside is the same and only the IP addresses are different.